# Using jQuery inside of an href tag

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to find a way to call a jQuery statement from within an `<a>` tag in an `href` attribute. My code looks like this:

```
<a href="javascript:$('#myElement').addClass('test');">
```

When I click on this link the browser (Firefox) goes to a blank page with:

```
[object Object]
```

IMPORTANT: I am using a third-party plugin that generates the anchor tag code so I don't have access to add the code into the onclick event for the `<a>` tag. I would also prefer not to have to introduce a function as a wrapper to the statement as we're using AJAX.

The funny thing is, this works:

```
<a href="javascript:alert('test');">
```

Is there a reason why jQuery statements don't work in an `href` attribute? Is it the leading dollar sign causing issues? Is there a way to make it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The return value of a `javascript:` URI is the data used to make up the page the browser should go to.

A call to `jQuery` will return a jQuery object. A call to `alert` will return `undefined` (which is treated as a No Content response).

You could wrap the script in a call to `void()` (passing the return value of `jQuery` as an argument to it), but I'd really advise sorting out the underlying system so you don't have to use `javascript:` URIs in the first place.

Comment: Thanks Quentin -- I hadn't thought of using the jQuery object as an argument in the void function. That worked beautifully. I'm using an old legacy script written by another developer that I don't have time to re-write at the moment, otherwise I would avoid javascript: altogether.

Thanks though, appreciate another brain on this problem.

Comment: FYI: Just to make the answer entirely complete, the value of the HREF attribute should be:

javscript:void($('#myElement').addClass('test'))

Answer (score 3):

You can get around this by wrapping the call in a function:

```
<a href="javascript:(function(){$('#myElement').addClass('test');})()">asdf</a>
```

But the better bet is using the javascript click event:

```
<a href="#" onclick="$('#myElement').addClass('test');return false;">asdf</a>
```

or even better, hooking up elsewhere:

```
<a href="#" id="somelink">asdf</a>

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("#somelink").click(function() {
        $('#myElement').addClass('test');
        return false;
    });
});
```